# Using php to display object at a specific time

Tags: php, time, show-hide

This may seem like a simple thing but I just can't get my head around it. How do I use php to display a div on a website at a specific time for only a duration? Eg. Show object for 10min every hr.

Ok, I have an object ie ahajsjajshaksjaksjiajsns which is displayed on a website when visitors visit the site. But I don't want it to show all the time but say every hr. And to disappear from the website after 10min.

Comment: What kinda object  ? where you want to display ? give more details

Comment: What you had tried so far ? Your code please

Comment: Sorry guys am using a phone to type this so can't really paste codes here. But I want to display a div on a website at a specific time for a duration. That's why I want to do.

Comment: probably better using jquery, but we need more infromation

Comment: Please be much more specific so we don't need to guess what you really want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(date("i") < 10) echo "...";
```

This code will echo `...` every hour from minute 0 to minute 9. e.g. 8.00-8.09, 9.00-9.09, 10.00-10.09, ...

PHPs date function is able to give you values you can check against a specific date. For more information see [the docs](http://php.net/date).

Comment: Thanx champ...works like a charm ;) but this works for every hr. Is there anything I can do if I want it for 2hrs intervals? Just asking :) @kekub

Comment: Sure, you can simply add another condition: `if(date("i") < 10 && date("H") % 2) echo "...";`. This will echo `...` every odd hour. For every even hour check for `date("H") % 2 == 0`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't coded anything web in a few years, so forgive me if I'm rusty but:

You can't do this all serverside. The page will compile but unless the user refreshes the page, the object in question will be forever available.

What you want to do, is use [kekub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3464036/kekub)'s example to generate the following code only if it's within the time range, but also include JavaScript to destroy it when time is up:

```
$time = date("i");

if($time < 10){
    $timeToExpire = 10 - $time;

    echo "<div id="yourObject">I will expire soon!</div>;

    echo"<script type = 'text/javascript'>setTimeout(function() {
         $('#yourObject').fadeOut('fast');
    }, ".$timeToExpire * 10000.");</script>";  // * milliseconds e.g 6 minutes
}
```

I haven't tested it but what should happen is, the webpage will generate the div and also the code needed to hide it when the time is up (say there is only 6 minutes left to show it).

Although I think personally you should do this all in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can set time for two divs using setTimeout and can call divs in that function

setTimeout(function(){page2(mintime)},10000);
setTimeout(function(){page1(mintime)},10000);

Comment: Thanx. But pls how do u set the time here? The div needs to show every hr n last for only 10min

Answer (score 0):

This kind of function usually should not be done in server side. Anyway if you want to achieve this using PHP you can have something like this:

```
while (true) {
    $result = yourfunction;
    if (resultIsGood) {
        break;
    }
    sleep(3);
}
```

You can sleep in a loop